# access to path denied while uploading photo into online database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

--code behind--

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));

            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please Upload a Photo')", true);

            }
            string path = "Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
string ins=insert into tbl(image)values('"+path+"');
con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(ins, con);
                int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (row > 0)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Thank You For Registering With Us..Press Cancel To Continue!!')", true);

                }
                con.Close();
```

--source error--

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\HostingSpaces\acquircom\acquirosoft.com\wwwroot\Deepam\Uploads\actiiv_fitband_003.png' is denied.

Comment: You will need write permission on "Uploads" folder. Make sure you give rights only to iis users per your IIS version, don't give permission to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS App Pool user needs write access to that folder.  From the path it looks like the site is being hosted by a third-party.  Most hosts set folder rights to read by default, but you should be able to change to read/write in your host's control panel.